# If the difference between the input and the variable is over 30 or over then the text for #feedback should be .

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie working on an assignment. I need to compare a variable to an input. If the difference between the randomNumber variable and the input is 30 or greater then I want the text for #feedback to be "very cold".
Example 1: randomNumber = 50 and input value = 20 then #feedback should be "very cold"

Example 2: randomNumber = 50 and input value = 90 then #feedback should be "very cold"

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var randomNumber = 0;
  var userGuess = 0;
  var guessCount = 0;



  //generates number
  function randomNumberGenerator() {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
    console.log("random number= " + randomNumber);
  }

  randomNumberGenerator();
   
  //starts new game
  function newGame(){
    guessCount = 0;
    randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
    console.log("new number is " + randomNumber);
  }

  //user guess
  function compareGuess(){  
    if ($("#userGuess").val() == randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('You Win!');
    }
  }

  //sets number of counts
  function setCount(count){
    $('#count').text(guessCount);
  }


  //submit
  $('#guessButton').click(function() {
    compareGuess();
  });

  //click for new game
  $( ".new" ).click(function() {
    newGame();
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="game"> <!-- Guessing Section -->
   
  <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

    <form>
      
      <input type="text" 
             name="userGuess" 
             id="userGuess" 
             class="text" 
             maxlength="3" 
             autocomplete="off" 
             placeholder="Enter your Guess" 
             required/>
      
       <input type="button" 
               id="guessButton" 
               class="button"   
               name="submit" 
               value="Guess"/>
      
 </form>
   
    <p>
      Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!
    </p>
   
 <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

 </ul>

</section>
```

JS Fidde: https://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/w8jxqjem/6/

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information, thank you!

Comment: You don't say what your problem is. For starters as it is a `form` it will submit and throw away the code each time.

Comment: If the refresh is the issue, as you pick your random number on the ready function, a new one will be pick each time the page refresh.

Comment: In the question, the button is `type="button"`, but on the fiddle it is `type="submit"`. Since you are not doing anything on the server, you want the first one of those.

Comment: Please read [MCVE]. You need to describe what your program is currently doing, and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You just need this code in your `compareGuess()`

```
if(input > randomNumber)
{
    if((input - randomNumber) > 30)
  {
    $("#feedback").text("Very cold!");
  }
}
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/w8jxqjem/9/)**

---

**SNIPPET**

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var randomNumber = 0;
  var userGuess = 0;
  var guessCount = 0;



  //generates number
  function randomNumberGenerator() {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    console.log("random number= " + randomNumber);
  }

  randomNumberGenerator();
  //starts new game
  function newGame() {
    guessCount = 0;
    randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    console.log("new number is " + randomNumber);
  }

  //user guess
  function compareGuess() {
    console.log("Guessing");
    var input = parseInt($("#userGuess").val());

    if (input == randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('You Win!');
    }

    if (input > randomNumber) {
      if ((input - randomNumber) >= 30) {
        $("#feedback").text("Very cold!");
      }
    }
  }

  //sets number of counts
  function setCount(count) {
    $('#count').text(guessCount);
  }


  //submit
  $('#guessButton').click(function() {
    compareGuess();
  });

  //click for new game
  $(".new").click(function() {
    newGame();
  });


});




$(document).ready(function() {

  /*--- Display information modal box ---*/
  $(".what").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(1000);

  });

  /*--- Hide information modal box ---*/
  $("a.close").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut(1000);
  });

});
```

```css
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Common Styles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*float styles*/

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #394264;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 96%;
  margin: 0.8em auto;
  font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #1F253D;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Header Styles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  padding: 1em;
}
nav ul li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
nav ul li:first-child {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
}
/*style for hidden modal*/

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
.content {
  color: #fff;
  background: #e74c3c;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 15%;
  margin: auto auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.content h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.content > div {
  padding: 15px 40px 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}
.content > div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: justify;
}
.content > div ul {
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  padding: 0 0 30px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
.content > div ul li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.content > div ul li strong {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.content > div a {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background: #1F253D;
  color: #95a5a6;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Game Section Styles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.game {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #394264;
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: rgb(26, 31, 52) 1px 1px, rgb(26, 31, 52) 2px 2px, rgb(26, 31, 52) 3px 3px, rgb(26, 31, 53) 4px 4px, rgb(26, 32, 53) 5px 5px, rgb(27, 32, 53) 6px 6px, rgb(27, 32, 54) 7px 7px, rgb(27, 32, 54) 8px 8px, rgb(27, 32, 54) 9px 9px, rgb(27, 33, 55) 10px 10px, rgb(27, 33, 55) 11px 11px, rgb(28, 33, 55) 12px 12px, rgb(28, 33, 56) 13px 13px, rgb(28, 34, 56) 14px 14px, rgb(28, 34, 56) 15px 15px, rgb(28, 34, 57) 16px 16px, rgb(29, 34, 57) 17px 17px, rgb(29, 34, 57) 18px 18px, rgb(29, 35, 58) 19px 19px, rgb(29, 35, 58) 20px 20px, rgb(29, 35, 58) 21px 21px, rgb(29, 35, 59) 22px 22px, rgb(30, 35, 59) 23px 23px, rgb(30, 36, 59) 24px 24px, rgb(30, 36, 60) 25px 25px, rgb(30, 36, 60) 26px 26px, rgb(30, 36, 60) 27px 27px, rgb(31, 37, 61) 28px 28px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #cc324b;
  padding: 1em 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}
.game p {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#count {
  color: #f39c12;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8em 0;
  margin: 0.8em auto 0;
  background: #50597b;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #1f253d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
input.button {
  background: #1F253D;
  color: #95a5a6;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
}
input.button:hover {
  background: #e64c65;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #95a5a6;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #95a5a6;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #95a5a6;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #95a5a6;
}
ul.guessBox {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  background: #11a8ab;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul.guessBox li {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #1a4e95;
  padding: 0.3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0.2em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Top Navigation -->
<nav>
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a class="what" href="#">What ?</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="new" href="#">+ New Game</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Modal Information Box -->
<div class="overlay" id="modal">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>What do I do?</h3>
    <div>
      <p>This is a Hot or Cold Number Guessing Game. The game goes like this:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>1. I pick a <strong>random secret number</strong> between 1 to 100 and keep it hidden.</li>
        <li>2. You need to <strong>guess</strong> until you can find the hidden secret number.</li>
        <li>3. You will <strong>get feedback</strong> on how close ("hot") or far ("cold") your guess is.</li>
      </ul>
      <p>So, Are you ready?</p>
      <a class="close" href="#">Got It!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- logo text -->
<h1>HOT or COLD</h1>

</header>

<section class="game">
  <!-- Guessing Section -->

  <h2 id="feedback">Make your Guess!</h2>

  <!--<form>-->
  <input type="text" name="userGuess" id="userGuess" class="text" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your Guess" required/>
  <input type="submit" id="guessButton" class="button" name="submit" value="Guess" />
  <!--</form>-->

  <p>Guess #<span id="count">0</span>!</p>

  <ul id="guessList" class="guessBox clearfix">

  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: also, I disabled the `form`tag in your html, jsfiddle didn't like as much as I thought.

Comment: and as it seems, I forgot to include the other way, where the input could be smaller than the randomNumber, but you get the idea. It's not that hard to figure it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is how to check if the difference between the randomnNumber and user's input is greater than 30. Here's the solution in JavaScript:

```
var userInput = $("#userGuess").val();    
var difference = Math.abs(randomNumber - userInput);

if (difference > 30){
    $('#feedback').text('very cold');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, as many have mentioned already. You need to remove the `<form>` tags and change the input type from `submit` to `button`.

I've looked at your code and i've altered it in a way of showing you how the check can be done. Check the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1w17oh13/3/

All the checks will be done inside the `compareGuess()`

```
//user guess
function compareGuess()
{  
var guess = parseInt($("#userGuess").val());

guessCount += 1;
guesses.push(guess);
guessDistance = Math.abs(randomNumber - guess);
previousGuessDistance = Math.abs(randomNumber - guesses[guesses.length - 2]);

if (guess == randomNumber) 
{
  $('#feedback').text('You Win!');
}
else {
  console.log(guess, randomNumber, previousGuessDistance, guessDistance);
  if (isNaN(previousGuessDistance)) {
    if (guess > randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('Guess lower!');
    } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('Guess higher!');
    }

  } else if (guessDistance > previousGuessDistance) {
    if (guess > randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('Getting colder');
    } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('Getting colder, guess higher!');
    }
  } else if (guessDistance < previousGuessDistance) {
    if (guess > randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('Getting hotter, guess lower!');
    } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('Getting hotter, guess higher!');
    }
  } else if (guessDistance === previousGuessDistance) {
    if (guess > randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('On fire, guess lower!');
    } else if (guess < randomNumber) {
      $('#feedback').text('On fire, guess higher!');
    }
  } else {
    $('#feedback').text('ERROR: Your guess must be a number between 1 and 100').css({
      color: 'red'
    });
  }
}
}
```